# OS X how to get application base path, out of executable full path

Tags: c++, macos

I've got a tool that interrogate external processes, and I'd like to add some objective-c queries that work on Info.plist file.

In order to do so, I'm using the following code with application base path as an input (i.e. /Applications/Notes.app/)

```
NSDictionary* infoDict = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:vlcFilePath] infoDictionary];
```

however, I can only get the executable path from the remote process (i.e. /Applications/Notes.app/Contents/MacOS/Notes) and I'd like to make the conversion to base path.

I've Used std::strings with rfind in order to get what i need, but i wonder if there's more conventional way that is can also run on some valid non-convensional path formations (my code is vulnerable to paths that contain several consecutive slashes like /Application/Notes.app/Contents/MacOS//Notes).

my code (just equal to go backwards to parent dir 3 times) :

```
for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    const size_t last_slash_idx = executable.rfind('/');
    if (std::string::npos != last_slash_idx) {
        executable = executable.substr(0, last_slash_idx);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

okey, i've found some neat solution after several tries using string.rfind method that look for the last occurrence of ".app" and then truncate the string from that index onwards.

```
std::string app_suffix(".app");
int split_idx = executable.rfind(app_suffix);
executable = executable.substr(0,split_idx+app_suffix.size());
```